# How do I prevent Sublime Text from splitting up HTML tags when wrapping?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, word-wrap

When word wrap is enabled in Sublime Text, it wraps the `<` and `>` separately from the tag name. I would like to keep the opening and/or ending carat together with its tag name.

What is happening:

```
<p><strong>A wrapped line</
strong>
Another wrapped line blah</
p>
```

What I would like:

```
<p><strong>Test HTML blah blah
</strong>
Another wrapped line blah
</p>
```